# How can I use Chromecast code with Cheapcast?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to understand how I can use ChromeCast in my app using this code: https://github.com/googlecast/cast-ios-demo-player. 
But I don't have yet ChromeCast and I have to test how the code working with Cheapcast. 
I found here: https://github.com/mauimauer/cheapcast/issues/6 some istructions, but I don't understand. To operate the demo code, I have need to replace @"[YOUR_APP_NAME]" with an hex app identifier (from Google whitelist email). But I don't have ChromeCast so I don't have this identifier. How can I do? Using Cheapcast what can I put into @"[YOUR_APP_NAME]" place?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
In order to test a chromecast app, you need to specifically whitelist some devices to work with the application.

Given the Cheapcast app doesn't come with a serial number that you can send to google, you can't whitelist it. As such you won't be able to get an App_id nor will you see your cheapcast in the list of available devices even if you do.